# Printing SVG from Browser (IE and FF)

Tags: printing, svg

I have a project that generated a svg representation of a tree and saves it as a svg.

I tryed to print the resulted svg file from the browser (any browser) but it prints only the upper left corner that fitts the screen. The rest is clipped.

I tryed embedding it on a html, I tryed giving fixed dimensions to the svg file, but the problem persists.

I searched this topic intensivley but no one seems to have this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to print from the browser? If you just have an svg you need to print you should be able to control the printing better from inkscape or another similar program.

Comment: Please provide more details: how is the SVG included in the web page (or is it being browsed directly as an SVG file)? What are the dimensions of the SVG element itself? What browser versions are you using? Are you using any SVG libraries (e.g. SVGWeb) or plug-ins (e.g. Adobe SVG Viewer) to display the SVG?

Comment: @Drooling_Sheep: Yes, i need to print the svg form the browser.

Comment: @Phrogz: I am using Adobe svg Viewer (the plugin), and i"m not using any libraries. I'm generating the svg dinamically in java based on a tree structure and writing in a buffer, so the size varies from case to chese. The biggest one was approx. 4000px x11000. And the resulted svg file is offered as a download. I am using IE 7 and FF 3.6. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @macgyverx86 Do you realize that the Adobe SVG Viewer was last substantively developed 10 years ago, had a tiny security-fix release 5 years ago, and that all support for it was officially discontinued [over two years ago](http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/)? And that IE7 was released over 4 years ago? You're asking about problems with incredibly old and broken technology. I would recommend that you use modern browsers and native SVG support, with an [SVGWeb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) shim if you must support older versions of IE.

Comment: @Phrogz: Yes i realise that ie7 sucks but these are the specifications :D

Comment: FWIW, Chrome and IE9 fails to print SVGs properly too...